# Can't get AJAX and PHP working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

So here is the scenario:

I have HTML, JS, and PHP Files.  Within the PHP File is an associative array of default values to fill out various form elements on the HTML file.  I am attempting to use AJAX to take the files from the PHP Files, and put them in the corresponding form elements.  However nothing is working.....

Below is the code for the corresponding files.  Any help figuring this out is greatly appreciated :)

**HTML**

```
<html>
  <body>  
    <h1>Form Validation</h1>

    <form id="PersonForm">
      Name: <input type="text" id="name" name="name"> <br>
      Postal Code: <input type="text" id="postal" name="postal"> <br>
      Phone Number: <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone"> <br>
      Address: <input type="text" id="address" name="address"> <br>
      <input type="submit">
    </form>

    <a href="frontend.html">Refresh</a> 
    <a id="InsertDefault" href="">Insert Default Data</a>
    <br>

    <ul id="errors"></ul>
    <p id="success"></p>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

// Return JSON default data if requested
if ($_REQUEST['act'] == 'default')
{
  $defaultData = array('name' => "Jane",
                   'postal' => "L5B4G6",
                   'phone' => "9055751212",
                   'address' => "135 Fennel Street");

  echo json_encode($defaultData);
}
?>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

  $("#InsertDefault").click(function()
  {      
     // make an AJAX call here, and place results into the form
    $.post('backend.phps', 
        { act: 'default' },
        function(data) {
            for (var key in  data) {
            document.getElementById(key).value = data[key] }
            },
            'json');
    // prevents link click default behaviour
    return false;
  });
});
```

As a side note, I always have trouble with web development stuff because I have no idea how to properly debug what I am doing.  If anyone has any tips on what are some useful tricks/tools to use for debugging web code, I'd be more than happy to get some input on that too.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Does the AJAX fire? Open the developer console, go to the network tab, and click your link. Check the `preserve log` checkbox. Is `backend.phps` the real name of your script? Did you modify the configuration to handle `phps`?

Comment: @chris85 yes backend.phps is the real name of my script.  How would I modify configuration for phps?  I haven't had any issues with that file extension before.

Answer (score 0):

For ajax code request use:

```
$("#InsertDefault").click(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "backend.phps",
    data: "act=default&name=test&phone=test", //Something like this
    success: funtion(msg){
      console.log(msg);
    },
    beforeSend:function(dd){
      console.log(dd)
    }
  });
});
```

and in your `backend.php` file

```
if ($_REQUEST['act'] == 'default'){
   //echo $_REQUEST['name'];
}
```

And for simple debugging use browsers' console, right click on the page and click **Inspect Element**. (Simple)
You can also install **Firebug** extension on Mozilla Firefox and then right click on the page and click on **inspect Element with firebug**. after this click on the **Console** tab there.

These are the basic and simple debugging for simple ajax request.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, only one slight hiccup.  This is actually for a school project and we aren't allowed to modify the php code in any way :\

Comment: now see the code how you need to post the act param and get that inside PHP file

Comment: You should include `error` alongside success callbacks and you forgot you add `preventdefault(e)` :-)

Answer (score 0):

Per the newest Ajax documentation your ajax should include the Success and Failure callbacks where you can handle the response being sent from your PHP.

This should work with you existing PHP file.

Ajax

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
   //look for some kind of click below
            $(document).on('click', '#InsertDefault', function (event) {

            $.ajax({
                url: "/backend.phps",
                type: 'POST',
                cache: false,
                data: {act: 'default'},
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (output, text, error)
                {

     for (var key in  output.defaultData) {
    document.getElementById(key).value = data[key] 
    }
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                {
                   //Error handling for potential issues.
                    alert(textStatus + errorThrown + jqXHR);
                }
            })
        })
preventDefault(event);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm at least getting something now.  However it is an error message :P  What I am seeing is DEFAULT 501 (Not Implemented).  Where do I go from here?

Comment: That means that the request method is not supported by the server, which would be an issue when sending to the PHP file. Servers are only required to support GET and POST so when it see's $_REQUEST it freaks because it doesn't exist.

Comment: Question. Instead of type: 'Post' would I instead be able to put something in akin the to { act: 'default' } I was using in my original code?  The PHP is set up to deal with $_REQUEST calls as opposed to $_POST or $_GET

Comment: You could try changing the ` type: 'POST'` to `type: 'REQUEST'` But that shouldn't be necessary as $_REQUEST in PHP is just an array containing both POST and GET Variables sent.

Comment: The above would just change the header that is sent to your server, though the not implemented sounds like a wrong server config.

Comment: Okay.  Just to add some more info, the rest of the PHP file contains the info on Validating the form.  For that section is looks for a $_REQUEST['act'] or 'validate'.  So again, I'm not sure if post or get will work.  obviously I am not very good at this stuff >_<

Comment: Is it looking for `$_REQUEST['act'] == "Validate";`

Comment: yes.  And as you can see in the code above, the first segment is looking for $_REQUEST['act'] == 'default'

Comment: Then I would almost certainly say that your server is having issues serving .phps files and probably needs the config loaded in the PHP.INI

Comment: So should I try remaking the PHPS file as a PHP file and see if that works?

Comment: I don't think it would hurt to try, though I'm not sure how much more I can assist you here as this is going a little outside of my knowledge :-)

Comment: Alright, well thank you very much for all the help you have been.  Much appreciated :)

Comment: Maybe consider opening up another question with the 501 error and see if someone else knows the last bit of the jigsaw :-)